# Is there a difference between Protected Internal and Internal Protected?

Tags: c#, .net, internal, protected, access-modifiers

```
public class TestClass
{
    protected internal int FieldA;
    internal protected int FieldB;    
}
```

Is there a difference between Protected Internal and Internal Procted Members?

Comment: No there is not. However, don't fall into the trap of not realising it means `protected || internal`. It does not mean `protected && internal`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a difference between `protected internal` and `internal protected`
>   members?

There is no difference between them.

`protected internal` means `protected` OR `internal`.

`internal protected` means `internal` OR `protected`.

> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in
>   which it is declared, **or** from within a derived class in another
>   assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class
>   declaration that derives from the class in which the protected
>   internal element is declared, and it must take place through an
>   instance of the derived class type.

Of the two, `protected internal` is commonly used. There is no reference to `internal protected` on the **[MSDN page about Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)**.

Also check out Phil Haack's blog post **[`What Does Protected Internal Mean?`](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/10/29/what-does-protected-internal-mean.aspx)**

Answer (score 2):

No, no difference. You can declare them in any order you want. Just like you can declare `static` before or after the access modifier.

The only real difference should be what you and your team decide on. Typically you'll want to stick to *one* style to avoid confusion or assumptions, or at least make things consistent when reading it.

EDIT: Though, now that I think of it, I don't recall seeing `"internal protected"` often. On the [MSDN page for access modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx), it does list it as `"protected internal"`, so maybe stick with that as it may be considered "more standard".

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

Both variants define a member that is accessible from the same assembly AND from descendant classes.

Comment: In this particular case, both "and" and "or" will have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bitwise operation with a logical "OR" => Internal : from the same assembly. protected : from a derived class. "protected AND internal" is no sense :-)